# How can I change the origin point of an Image inside a PictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Flash has an option exactly like this, where you set the registration point:

[image]

When I attempt to do anything,  set the Location of a Image by extending Panel, trying to offset Image within PictureBox... Nothing I can find achieves this because:

For example, this:

[image]

If there is no way to do this in C# that is OK. I miss understood the technology and will go with MainMa.

Comment: If you know the dimensions of the `PictureBox` then you can work this out yourself.

Comment: How are you drawing your assets?  Are they controls that you are placing on the form, or are you manually drawing in the OnPaint event handler?

Comment: Yes I agree, and I know them. I looked first for a way to translate the `Image` of a `PictureBox` but I was unsuccessful. I also tried to make a `Panel` which contained a `PictureBox` but when I set the Location of the `PictureBox` to negative values, I stopped seeing the `PictureBox` but I could see the `Panel`.

Comment: Thanks for OnPaint heads up. Right now I am just basically adding a whole load of `PictureBox` to a `Panel` "canvas" and I can move them all around with manually messing around with Mouse Up/Down/Move. In more familiar languages, I would shift the anchor/origin of the "Group" to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.size.aspx) of the picture is available through two properties:

- `PictureBox.Size.Height`
- `PictureBox.Size.Width`

and you set the [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx) by doing:

```
PictureBox.Location = new Point(x, y)
```

So to shift the picture, you do:

```
private void CenterPicture(PictureBox picture)
{
    if (picture == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(
            "picture",
            "The picture should be specified.");
    }

    var x = picture.Location.X - picture.Size.Width / 2;
    var y = picture.Location.Y - picture.Size.Height / 2;
    picture.Location = new Point(x, y);
}
```

Note: remember to check [`SizeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx). Some [values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx) of this property may resize the image, which will lead to it not being centered when applying the `CenterPicture` method.

Comment: Thanks MainMa. I was hoping I could remove the need to deal with this additional calculation everywhere, since the editor deals with circular shaped entities, to assume they were already centered would keep everything pretty neat and uniform.

Comment: @Clark: I'm not sure I understand (even after reading the comments on the original question). What about creating your own class `CenteredPictureBox` which inherits from `PictureBox` and adjusts automatically the position of the picture according to its location and size? This means that you would use the object as any other, without having to "deal with this additional calculation everywhere".